# Computer quickly deactivates after turning on with boot on power in BIOS setting

Tags: boot, laptop, bios, power-supply

Computer specs: Lenovo X220i Tablet running Windows 7 64 bit (I doubt knowing the OS will help, but just in case)

In the BIOS I have enabled the setting 'power on when AC attached' so the computer *should* turn on when it is connected to the AC.  It does turn on, but only for about 3 seconds then turns off.  (Note, when it turns off, it makes a small 'beep' sound, which I normally only hear when the computer is turned off by force i.e. when I hold down the power button).  I have a BIOS Lock setup as well, but normally when booting the computer will stay turned on for far longer than 3 seconds without input before it shuts itself down.  Further, the computer is connected by USB port to a Toshiba Dynadock U3.0 if that is of any help.

My question is what I can do to fix this issue, as it doesn't sound very healthy for the computer to be doing this.

Comment: Oh, and if anyone wants any more information that might help, just post a comment and I'll be more than glad to give it to you if I can!

Comment: Just a guess:  Disable the feature?

Comment: @DanielRHicks - which feature: the BIOS Lock or the activate on AC?  If the latter, I've disabled it and re-enabled it and the problem still occurs.

Comment: @DanielRHicks, sorry it took so long to try it out, but I was trying all sorts of other things; works out if you disable the BIOS Lock (but not necessarily the BIOS Lock on the HDD), it works.  If you post it as an answer I'll accept.  Cheers

Comment: Actually, I was thinking about disabling 'power on when AC attached'.

Comment: @DanielRHicks ah, well as I said I disabled and re-enabled with no effect, but disabling the BIOS lock works.  I'll post it as the answer then, but thanks for stirring the idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, having a BIOS lock prevents the feature form working properly.  By disabling the BIOS lock, it works fine, but there is no need to disable the BIOS lock on the HDD.